# Referencing Variables in .cfi_escape

Tags: gnu, gnu-assembler, dwarf

I have a trampoline written in assembly that needs to stash away the return address of a function in a global variable like this:

```
#define DW_CFA_expression         0x10
#define DW_OP_addr                0x03
#define DW_OP_deref               0x06

trampoline:
        .cfi_startproc
        pop ret_addr // store return address in global var named ret_addr
        .cfi_escape DW_CFA_expression, DW_OP_addr, ret_addr, DW_OP_deref
        // do stuff
        jmp *ret_addr // return to the stored address
        .cfi_endproc

        .globl trampoline
        .type trampoline, @function

        .data
ret_addr:
        .zero 4
```

and I need stack unwinding to work with this trampoline.  Compiling that code using gcc with no options gives:

```
$ gcc trampoline.S just_main.c
/tmp/ccZuu7aa.o:(.eh_frame+0x2d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_8 against `.data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The assembler seems to have correctly instructed the linker to replace that `ret_addr` in the `.cfi_escape` with the address of that symbol.  However, `.cfi_escape` expects a comma-separated list of bytes, so the emitted relocation is 8 bits, which is way too small.

How can I refer to the address of a variable inside a `.cfi_escape` directive?  Is this possible at all?  If it is possible, is there a way to take it further and have `ret_addr` be a thread-local variable defined in a different module?

I'm working on an up-to-date amd64 Ubuntu GNU/Linux, if that makes a difference.  The whole toolchain is GNU, and I don't care about portability.